# Style Pygments at PythonTeX

Tags: minted, python, pygments

Can I use style pygmentize with Pygments at PythonTeX. Let MWE like this :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\begin{document}
\begin{pygments}[style= murphy]{python} % murpyhy is style from pygmentize
#!/usr/bin/env python
import Tkinter as tk
class Application(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, master=None):
tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
self.grid()
self.createWidgets()
def createWidgets(self):
self.quitButton = tk.Button(self, text='Quit',
command=self.quit)
self.quitButton.grid()
app = Application()
app.master.title('Sample application')
app.mainloop()
\end{pygments} 
\end{document}
```

And I will get style Pygmentize  like this :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{murphy}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[mathescape]{python}
#!/usr/bin/env python
import Tkinter as tk
class Application(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, master=None):
tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
self.grid()
self.createWidgets()
def createWidgets(self):
self.quitButton = tk.Button(self, text='Quit',
command=self.quit)
self.quitButton.grid()
app = Application()
app.master.title('Sample application')
app.mainloop()
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

The result above it, use minted package but  i need use pythontex package because simple with my document and the screenshoot the result :

[image: minted style]

**Any solution to solve it ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if the style can be changed mid document, but this works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pygopt={style=murphy}]{pythontex}
\begin{document}

\begin{pygments}{python}
#!/usr/bin/env python
import Tkinter as tk
class Application(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, master=None):
tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
self.grid()
self.createWidgets()
def createWidgets(self):
self.quitButton = tk.Button(self, text='Quit',
command=self.quit)
self.quitButton.grid()
app = Application()
app.master.title('Sample application')
app.mainloop()
\end{pygments}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is pygopt ? Where can i found  more documentation about pygments style at pythontex like  listing package ? Such as : line color, background color, line number ,etc

Comment: @Hirwanto I found it in the documentation of PythonTeX.

Comment: ouwh, ok , sorry , i have old documentation pythontex, thank for your information.

Comment: I tried to compile your code but got as a result **??PythonTex??** - I installed python-pygments. Do I need anything else?

Comment: @adam Did you do `pdflatex` `pythontex` `pdflatex`?

Comment: @egreg thank you, now it works. Do I need to compile the document only once with pythontex? Or do I need to do it every time when I do changes?

Comment: @Adam You need to run `pythontex` when some change is made to some `pygments` environment.